# concate values that has already been concated using "FOR XML PATH"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (T1) that contains a column (lets call it OrderNumber) with concatenated value by using FOR XML PATH. Originally these OrderNumber are concated based on a value V1, now I need to concate these OrderNumber again based on a new value V2 to create a new table (T2). Both V1 and V2 exist in table T1, and V1 is actually a sub-value of V2.

I tried to do another FOR XML PATH but it returns value in structure I cannot work with.

The correct OrderNumber returned as hyperlink in plain HTML form

```
<a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber=111"></a></br><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber=222"></a></br>
```

However, when I try concate it again it actually return the following

```
<OrderNumber><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber=111"></a></br><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber=222"></a></br><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber=333"></a></br></OrderNumber>
```

I tired removing the OrdrNumber tag in code behind but it will not work. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[Edit]

The outcome table is quite large so I will just post some relevant parts.

Table1

```
TONumber | TOKey | OrderNumber
3672     | 231   | <a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="111"></a></br><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="222"></a></br>
3672     | 232   | <a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="333"></a></br>
3821     | 265   | <a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="653"></a></br>
```

I have concatenated value OrderNumber in table 1 based on TOKey (V1) and also share the same TONumber(V2). What I trying to accomplish is the following

Expecting

```
TONumber | OrderNumber 
3672     | <a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="111"></a></br><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="222"></a></br><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="333"></a></br>
3821     | <a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="653"></a></br>
```

Real Outcome

```
TONumber | OrderNumber 
3672     | <OrderNumber><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="111"></a></br><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="222"></a></br><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="333"></a></br></OrderNumber>
3821     | <OrderNumber><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="653"></a></br></OrderNumber>
```

Code

```
select T1.TONumber,
       (select T2.OrderNumber
        from Table1 T2
        where T1.TONumber = T2.TONumber
        for xml path('')) as OrderNumber
from Table1 T1
group by TONumber
```

The reason I mentioned code behind is because I do not know how to accomplish my goal in SQL and just giving it a try. I am trying to see if it is possible to just keep it in the stored procedure.

Comment: sample data.... expected output....

Comment: @scsimon: you forgot "current query". But yes, like my esteemed colleague says, show us everything you've got so far, don't make us guess. In particular, I can't make heads or tails about V1 being a "sub-value" of V2.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ah i did forget that. It's so rare to get sample data AND expected output that I auto upvote anyone who gives it (without having to be asked) regardless of how unclear the question is. Sad... and to think you get a badge for reading the help pages haha. If only people would read them. [Here's a good thread jchien66](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) aside from the [SO Help Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with emphasis on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Since your question includes "code behind" and manipulates URLs, is this ASP.NET (MVC)? If so, feel free to tag appropriately and show code. You may be using SQL in a way you're not supposed to be using SQL -- constructing links or complete HTML snippets is the sort of thing C# is typically better at.

Comment: OT: Are you sure about the `</br>` ???

Comment: @JeroenMostert are the information helpful? thanks!

Comment: @scsimon are the information helpful? thanks!

Comment: If `OrderNumber` actually contains HTML (as in, stored in an character field), that's a *really* bad design, because the paths to your application are now hardcoded in the database. If you are deriving these values dynamically from earlier code you don't show, it's not as bad, but still pretty bad. The `SONumber`s (wherever they come from) should be retrieved as `INT` values and formatted into HTML by the client logic. Don't treat your database as an HTML generator. That's OK for a one-off (or as an exercise), but not in a production application.

Comment: These paths are inserted into a temp table so I guess it is not as bad. I am advised to do it this way by my super so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure... using FOR XML again...

```
declare @table table (TONumber int, TOKey int, OrderNumber varchar(max))
insert into @table
values
(3672,231,'<a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="111"></a></br><a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="222"></a></br>'),
(3672,232,'<a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="333"></a></br>'),
(3821,265,'<a href="/checker/OrderInformation.aspx?SONumber="653"></a></br>')

select distinct
    t.TONumber
    ,stuff((
        SELECT ', ' + cast(t2.OrderNumber as varchar(max))
        FROM @table t2
        WHERE t2.TONumber = t.TONumber
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from 
    @table t
```

or you could use `group by t.TONumber` and remove the distinct

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try.

Comment: I see the trick is to cast the original OrderNumber as varchar, thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries @jchien66